# encoding url in web.config

Tags: asp.net

I have a url that I would like to put into my web.config file.

http://google.com?parcel&bob&&smith

I imagine that the .net run time is upset with the ampersand's so i encoded them to be
&amp.

http://google.com?parcel&ampbob&amp&ampsmith

This also doesn't work. Any ideas would be great, if you could supply a link to the documentation of why this is that would be even better. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you try this? (semicolons)

```
http://google.com?parcel&amp;bob&amp;smith
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper encoding for the ampersand is **&amp;** You are missing the **;** at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is because you are missing the ';'. Try to use the HttpUtility.HtmlEncode method for encoding....

Comment: Whoever modded this down should have explained why they did it.  I think the issue is that it's in web.config, and thus not something you can add with code.

Comment: Agreed. Anonymous downvoting is the bane of our voting system.

Comment: Thanks guys - I was not trying to say you should use HttpUtility in web.config but rather to help you to get an correctly encoded string... But that was not well explained.